# Binding the source of an Image to image resources

Tags: wpf, image

I'm buliding an application in which I present an image whose source changes when some int value changes.
To do that, I'm trying to bind the 'Source' property of the Image:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=Gas, Converter={StaticResource GasToImageSource}}"/>
```

(Gas is an int value). And the Converter:

```
public class GasToImageSource : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int gas_value = (int)value;
        if (gas_value <=500 )
            return SomeNameSpace.Properties.Resources.GAS_INDICATOR1;
        if (gas_value <=1000)
            return SomeNameSpace.Properties.Resources.GAS_INDICATOR2;
        if (gas_value <= 1500)
            return SomeNameSpace.Properties.Resources.GAS_INDICATOR3;

        return SomeNameSpace.Properties.Resources.GAS_INDICATOR4;
    }

   ...
}
```

But for some reason this doesn't work.
What's wrong with my binding?

Answer (score 1):

To use a string you can change the binding to this:

```
Source="{Binding Path=Gas, StringFormat={}/your_namespace;component/{0}, Converter={StaticResource GasToImageSource}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `ImageSource` object, not a string. Try something like that:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    int gas_value = (int)value;
    string res = SomeNameSpace.Properties.Resources.GAS_INDICATOR4;
    if (gas_value <=500 )
        res = SomeNameSpace.Properties.Resources.GAS_INDICATOR1;
    if (gas_value <=1000)
        res = SomeNameSpace.Properties.Resources.GAS_INDICATOR2;
    if (gas_value <= 1500)
        res = SomeNameSpace.Properties.Resources.GAS_INDICATOR3;

    BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
    img.BeginInit();
    img.UriSource = new Uri(res, UriKind.Relative);
    img.EndInit();
    return img;
}
```